# VBA - Office 365/SharePoint - How to get last modified date of file on Sharepoint?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365

The title sums this one up.

Basically I would like to download all files that have been modified in a specific range of times so I am in need of a way to get the last modified date of a file in Office365/SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TestWhen()

    SPFilePath = "http://teams.MyCompany.com/sites/PATH/PATH/Fulfillment/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

    Debug.Print SPLastModified(SPFilePath, "2021_MyFileName.xlsx")

End Sub


Function SPLastModified(SPUrl As String, SPFName As String)

    Dim PagesHTML As String
    Dim Dadate As String
    Dim DaDateEnd As String
    Dim arr() As String
    arr = Split(OutString, " ")
    Dim LastChange As Variant

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate SPUrl
        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        Do While .busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Do Until .readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        PagesHTML = ie.document.DocumentElement.outerHTML
    End With

' Get to File
    Dadate = InStr(PagesHTML, "FileLeafRef" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & SPFName)

' Get to Modified Date
    ModifiedText = "Modified" & Chr(34) & ": "
    Dadate = Dadate + InStr(Mid(PagesHTML, Dadate), ModifiedText)

    OutString = Mid(PagesHTML, Dadate + Len(ModifiedText), 27)

    arr = Split(OutString, " ")
   
    LastChange = arr(1) & " " & arr(2)    
    LastChange = arr(0) & "/" & Mid(arr(1), 6) & "/" & Mid(arr(2), 6, 4) & " " & LastChange

    SPLastModified = LastChange

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge there is no way change the date modified. One way would to do, would be to put a workflow and him have a break to the desired date and edit any column, but the modified person would also be changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I am not looking to change the modified date.  Just retrieve the modified date of specific files.

Comment: This is the problem. The date modified is lost when replaced. For the items from a list they contain no version. If your situation is in documents, you may have historical and versions or select to have history. If you have not selected the version history and not be in a library, the modified dates can not be recuparadas. I suggest that if you want to store, put a field to get the last modified date before you save the form.

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  These files have only 1 version, I am not changing or modifying anything.  All I want to do is get the date modified field that is displayed when you view the file in your browser however I need to get it pragmatically from a macro in Excel.